# FreeBSD - major and minor upgrades using ports?

Tags: package-management, freebsd, upgrade, bsd-ports

while upgrading my FreeBSD for the first time (from 10.0 --> 10.1) I got confused about the different possibilities.

As far as I understand, `freebsd-update` does a binary update of FreeBSD like `pkg` does. After the initial installation, I used ports to install, compile and update my system and I basically wonder, if I can not do the same for a minor upgrade. I am aware, that there is a source fetch and compile option, but it seems to me that (some) security updates then depend on keeping the SVN repository in sync.

a) What's the difference between a a normal program upgrade and a minor system upgrade?

b) Can I use the source distribution and keep it updated by the ports package management (without SVN checkouts)?

---

**Updates from #freebsd @ freenode**

RobotsOnDrugs: freebsd-update and the base svn repos are for base, while the ports tree and pkg are for third-party software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `freebsd-update` and `pkg upgrade` do very different things.

The `freebsd-update` will (binary) update your *base system*. The base system contains everything except `/usr/local`: check `/{,s}bin` and `/usr/{,s}bin` to what programs are shipped with the base system. The parts of base system don't appears in package database, it is a separated infrastructure. The whole base system developed by FreeBSD.

The `pkg upgrade` does different thing: it upgrades the packages. The packages are in `/usr/local`, they are "3th-party-apps" - developed by other people/companies/..., not FreeBSD.

a) System upgrade means upgrade the base system (`freebsd-upgrade`). The program update means upgrade of installed packages (in `/usr/local`, with `pkg upgrade` or with ports tree).

b) You can build your packages from ports with your options ("source-based") or you can use packages from repositories ("binary-based").
It's independent from the base system: you can update your base system with `freebsd-update` ("binary update") and you can build your base system from source.

If you want build packages from ports you should have ports tree. You can checkout with [portsnap](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=portsnap%288%29&sektion=).

I hope it's clear now.

**Update1** if you want build the base system from source, you should rebuild every update - see [Rebuilding World](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/makeworld.html). And should syncronize the source of course.

I think if you want a source-based system it's a good option to use binary *base system* (which contains a compiler (clang in 10.x) too) and build your desired applications (webserver, favorite editor, maybe window managers, browsers, office suite, etc.) from ports.

Comment: yes, thank you. So if I build the base system from source, how would I receive security updates?

Comment: See my edit (it's a bit long answer).